# C# Tweetinvi library - project build warning

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, tweetinvi

I create UWP solution with two project - Universal Windows App and Universal Windows Class Library. In the App project i made reference to the Library project.
Next step - I add with Nuget a Tweetinvi library (I trying different versions), and I have compilation warning:

> Perform remapping app.config for assembly XXX from version YYY

My output (sorry for ru language):

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: CommonLibrary, Конфигурация: Debug x86 ------
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll] в версию "4.0.10.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "0.0.0.0" [] в версию "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Xml.XmlSerializer, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "0.0.0.0" [] в версию "4.0.10.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Xml.XmlSerializer\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Diagnostics.Contracts, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "0.0.0.0" [] в версию "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.Contracts\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Xml.XDocument, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.XDocument\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Xml.XDocument.dll] в версию "4.0.10.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Xml.XDocument\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Xml.XDocument.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Linq.Queryable, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "0.0.0.0" [] в версию "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Linq.Queryable\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Linq.Queryable.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
... 
//I hid output simular items
...
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Text.Encoding.Extensions, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll] в версию "4.0.10.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Linq, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "0.0.0.0" [] в версию "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Linq\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Linq.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "0.0.0.0" [] в версию "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>  Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки "System.ServiceModel.Duplex, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" из версии "0.0.0.0" [] в версию "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Mikhail\.nuget\packages\System.ServiceModel.Duplex\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll] для разрешения конфликта и избежания предупреждения.
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3247: Обнаружены конфликты между различными версиями одной и той же зависимой сборки. В Visual Studio дважды щелкните это предупреждение (или выберите его нажмите клавишу ВВОД), чтобы исправить конфликты; в противном случае следующая привязка перенаправляет на узел "среды выполнения" в файле конфигурации приложения: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.XmlSerializer" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Contracts" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.XDocument" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq.Queryable" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Tools" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Dynamic.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Numerics" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ServiceModel.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Debug" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Globalization" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq.Parallel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ServiceModel.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Timer" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.RegularExpressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Requests" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Concurrent" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq.Expressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encoding" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.20.0" newVersion="4.0.20.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.NetworkInformation" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.IO" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.20.0" newVersion="4.0.20.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Resources.ResourceManager" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.20.0" newVersion="4.0.20.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Principal" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
1>  CommonLibrary -> D:\Documents\VisualStudioProjects\TwitterNotifier\CommonLibrary\bin\x86\Debug\CommonLibrary.dll
```

If I adding Tweetinvi library to my App project - the problem does not occur.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This should be the issue of TweetinviAPI V0.9.10.2 package, if you downgrade to **V0.9.10**, this issue will be resolved, I can see the tweet posted by my app:)

Please use NuGet Package Manager to update package to **0.9.10** version:
[image]

---

**Update:** I opened an Issue in its GitHub repository: https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/150

Answer (score 2):

In fact it is not an issue with the package but of the UAP. 
In any case you can now download the latest version (0.9.11.0) of Tweetinvi on nuget should work.

`Update-Package TweetinviApi` // if already installed

OR

`Install-Package TweetinviApi` // if not installed

If you want version 0.9.10.2 you can use the following :

`Install-Package TweetinviAPI -Version 0.9.10.2-W10-UAP -Pre`

The problem comes from UAP not handling correctly the .NET Framework 4.0 when using merged libraries. I have tried all solutions to fix the issue without being able to resolve it.

What it does is UAP with merged libraries does not look into the correct .NET Framework folder which should be `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`.

If you have any idea I am more than happy to hear about it!

Comment: Thankx, @Linvi I will go deeper later:)

Comment: Tweetinvi 0.9.11 package simply adds all the library one by one instead of having a merged library when it targets UAP.